# ASP.NET AutoPostback not functioning properly

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am having a problem with a div in my application.

I created a div called `divUpload` and I need it to be visible only if the selected value from the dropdown menu is "IN".
The first time when I open the page everything works fine (maybe because the first value in Dropdown(by default) is IN).
When I change the value, once again everything works fine, so the div dissapears.

THE PROBLEM is when I change it again into IN, now the div doesn't appear anymore :(

What can I do ?

The code is like below:

```
    <div style="height: 25px">
            <div style="float: left; width: 200px">
                <b>Protocol type:</b>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left: 205px">
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cboProtocolType" AutoPostBack="true" 
                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboSelectedProtocolType_IndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>

<div id="divUpload" runat="server">
    <div style="height: 25px">
        <div style="float: left; width: 200px">
            <b>Upload document:</b>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 205px">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadProtocolDocs" runat="server"  ToolTip="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and the code behind is :

```
protected void cboSelectedProtocolType_IndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboProtocolType.SelectedValue.Equals("IN"))
            {
                divUpload.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                divUpload.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show where you populate dropdownlist (Page_load?) and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is replacing :

```
if (cboProtocolType.SelectedValue.Equals("IN"))
```

with :

```
if (cboProtocolType.SelectedItem.ToString()=="IN")
```

and works fine :)

Thanks odinel :)

Answer (score 1):

How are you populating the dropdownlist? I hard coded the items like this, and it worked fine:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="cboProtocolType" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboSelectedProtocolType_IndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>IN</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>OUT</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

When 'IN' was selected, the DIV appeared. When 'OUT' selected, the DIV disappeared. Have you tried creating a blank page with just these two controls, to see if there's some other code on your page interfering with it?

Comment: I populate the dropdown list using this code :  Entity.ProtocolType = new ProtocolTypeManager().GetById(new Guid(cboProtocolType.SelectedValue));   It gets the values from database. Is it any problem if I hard code the values in aspx page ? Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Well, that depends really. If it's always going to be a simple In or Out dropdownlist, I'd leave it hard coded. If the values are likely to change, then dynamic values are better. Have you tried this?: cboProtocolType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "IN"

Comment: I also tried the answer you gave me, I hard coded them but it still doesn't work :/ I think I am missing something ...but don't know what.

Comment: Hmm, possibly something to do with postback...? There may be another control interfering with it also. I would try adding the items to a fresh, blank page in your project and working from there. The small code sample above on its own works OK

Comment: Heyyyyyyyyyy :) It works fine now :) All I had to do was putting this one cboProtocolType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "IN" you told me :)